# Spring boot Application Pods crashing in EKS

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-fargate

I have a spring boot application[java 11] hosted in AWS EKS Fargate with 2 replicas initially and HPA configured as well.

When I am doing load testing, both pods crash when the load increases and they will be restarted and then HPA kicks in and increase the pod count to 4.

I tried looking into the application logs and pod logs using --previous option as well But I couldn't understand the reason for the crash.

Could you help me with some pointers to trouble shoot this issue?

Comment: Look for GC logs, pod's memory usage. The pod might be crashing because of Out of memory issues.

Comment: Look for heap and thread dump too

Answer (score 3):

Kubernetes restarts a pod if a container uses more memory than the limit set for the container in the deployment file. Check your pod Memory metric if you are using Prometheus or any other cluster monitoring tool which gathers this data through metric server.

Check [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-memory-resource/#exceed-a-container-s-memory-limit) for more details.

`If a Container allocates more memory than its limit, the Container becomes a candidate for termination. If the Container continues to consume memory beyond its limit, the Container is terminated. If a terminated Container can be restarted, the kubelet restarts it, as with any other type of runtime failure.`

Comment: Pod Request Limit is 4Gi, Limit is 8Gi. I can see from the dashboard that each pod is consuming less than 1.5Gi of memory. App heap min size is 1Gi and max is 2Gi. From the analytic tool I could see each pod max heap size consumed is less than 1Gi only. So it is not about the resource limitation I think